# How to start with programming 3D simulations for school projects?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 3d, simulation

My task is to create 3D simulation of something like solar system but simpler.Simulation must have some input values that affects simulation ( some speeds, angles...). My programming knowledge is only ANSI C. My guess is to use C++ and OpenGL, maybe i can learn C++ but i have no idea what is OpenGL... From what to start? Can i use ansi c for programming that simulation?

Comment: http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: step 1: ask on stackoverflow, step 2: get a decent compiler, step 3: google

Comment: Of course you can use C. Most OpenGL tutorials are in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to I'd use Unity.  It allows you to write the logic code in C# and you'll be finished with a beautiful 3D demo by the end of the day.

If your project is more about learning 3D maths you'll be probably wanting to look at OpenGl.  For that you can use C/C++/Java/etc...

Comment: Its about 3D maths :) What software to use to combine C and OpenGL? There are many tutorials on opengl.. i cant find any for total beginner..

Comment: [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/), [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452744.aspx) and [OpenGL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) are your main choices.  Check out these [OpenGL tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/).